# NativeClient: manifest JSON parsing failed: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token

Tags: php, codeigniter

i will play rtsp video in codeigniter using vxgplayer, i have an error like this [error nativeclient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgzRg.png)

how to solve this?

controller

```
public function view($id_camera)
    {
        $data['terminal']= $this->Larangan_model->getTerminal();
        $data['view_camera'] = $this->Larangan_model->getCameraById($id_camera);
        $this->load->view('viewCamera', $data);

    }
```

model

```
public function viewCamera($id_camera)
    {
        $this->db->select("id_camera,link");
        $this->db->where('id_camera', $id_camera);
        $query = $this->db->get('camera');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

view

```
<?php foreach($view_camera as $key) { ?>
<div class="vxgplayer"
id="vxg_media_player1" 
width="1315"
height="615"
url="<?php echo $key->link ?>"
nmf-src="pnacl/Release/media_player.nmf"
nmf-path="media_player.nmf"
useragent-prefix="MMP/3.0"
latency="10000"
autohide="2"
volume="0.7"
autostart=true
avsync
mute
aspect-ratio
aspect-ratio-mode="1"
auto-reconnect>
</div>
```

Comment: model method name should be  `viewCamera` in your controller, should be like : `$this->Larangan_model->viewCamera($id_camera);`

Comment: still error like that